# PHP Multidimensional Array Rearranging

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sir,

I am confused what should be exact title of this issues. Below is my problem

I have a multidimensional array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => 9 Am
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-02
            [1] => 07 Pm
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => 11 Pm
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-04
            [1] => 03 Pm
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => 11 Am
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-02
            [1] => 05 Pm
        )

)
```

Now, I want to make unique date beside time should be into another array.
I want it as below...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9 Am
                    [1] => 11 Am
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-02
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 07 Pm
                    [1] => 05 Pm
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 Pm
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-04
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 03 Pm
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks in advance..

Regards,

Anwar

Comment: What's the purpose? Wouldn't you want the date to be the keys, rather than nesting them?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.

Actually I want to keep date into 0 index and times into 1 index inside another array

Comment: Even the insert would require a loop each time... this seems really inefficient for both creation and access. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something of that fashion should do the trick...

Its nowhere near the fastest way to do so but it should get you going and it is pretty easy to read/understand

```
// putting the times in a new array where the date is the key

$byDate = [];
foreach ($firstArray as [$date, $time]) {
    $byDate[$date][] = $time;
}


// going thru it again to have it the way you needed it

$newArray = [];
foreach ($byDate as $date => $times) {
    $newArray[] = [$date, $times];
}
```