# How to Array diff between two multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sir,

I have another query..

I have two Array and need array differ between two multidimensional Array ..

Array 1 :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9 am
                    [1] => 11 am
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-02
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 05 pm
                    [1] => 07 pm
                    [2] => 08 pm
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 pm
                    [1] => 12 pm
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-04
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 02 pm
                    [1] => 03 pm
                )

        )

)
```

Array Two :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9 am
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 pm
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-02
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 05 pm
                    [1] => 07 pm
                    [2] => 08 pm
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-04
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 02 pm
                    [1] => 03 pm
                )

        )

)
```

I need below result by array diff between above two array..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-01
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 am
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-11-03
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12 pm
                )

        )

)
```

Have there any easy way to resolved this..

Thanks in advance..

Regards,

Anwar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Comment: I think it works similar to what was suggested to you in the earlier question about building that array you diff here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441425/367456

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to iterate over all the elements of first array and compare it with the corresponding elements in the second array if they are different.

```
$a = [
[
    'a',
    [
        'b',
        'c'
    ]
],
[
    'd',
    [
        'e',
        'f',
    ]
]
];

$b = [
[
    'a',
    [
        'b',
        'c'
    ]
],
[
    'd',
    [
        'h',
        'f'
    ]
]
];

function array_difference($a, $b) {
if( ! is_array($a)) {
    if($a != $b)
    echo "$a <> $b: " . $a . PHP_EOL;
    return;
}

$rowsA = count($a); $rowsB = count($b);
if( $rowsA !== $rowsB ) {
    echo 'Both arrays are not similar.' . PHP_EOL;
    exit(0);
}

for($i=0; $i < count($a) ; $i++) {
    array_difference($a[$i], $b[$i]);
}

}

print(array_difference($a, $b));
```

Comment: output: e <> h: e